# spring integration outbound gateway rest ws read http_statusCode from response header

Tags: spring-integration

configuration of my application is like :

```
    <int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel"
    expression="''">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="60000"></int:poller>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="quakeinfo.channel">
    <int:queue capacity="10" />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="quakeinfotrigger.channel"></int:channel>

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="quakerHttpGateway"
    request-channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel" 
    url="http://fff.com/rest/objects"
    http-method="POST"
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
    charset="UTF-8"
    reply-timeout="5000"
     reply-channel="quakeinfo.channel">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

I need to handle errors according to http_statusCode on the response header. Can you tell me to intercept it in my code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you want to do.

There are lots of ways to use the header, for example:

You can subscribe a `<router/>` to `quakeinfo.channel` and route based on the header value.

You can use a service activator...

```
<service-activator input-channel="quakeinfo.channel" ref="foo" method="handle" />
```

and

```
public class Foo {

    public void handle(@Header("http_statusCode") HttpStatus statusCode) {
        ...
    }
}
```